# echo or >> (or something) fails when network connection has been idle for a long period?

Tags: networking, python, macos, smb

I have a script that takes several hours to finish (the script runs whisper and it is the whisper . At the end I `echo` and `>>` some results to a network volume mounted using SMB. This often fails for no particular reason. I suspect that the network connection gets into some kind of idle mode because there has been no traffic for a long period and when my script tries to write to it it doesn't "wake up" fast enough.

The script uses >> to add whisper's output to a file while executing. When that is done,  I then use echo to add some results at the end of the same file. Typically what happens is that some, but not all, of the output handled by >> is included in the file, followed by the string that is added using echo (and >>).

Whisper adds a timestamp to every line it outputs so if you use it on a recording that is 10 minutes, you get maybe 3 minutes of output (when you expect 10 minutes) followed by the line I use echo to add to the end of the same file.

In the GUI, if I access this network volume when it has been idle for a couple of hours, it takes some time for it to update/list it contents, while if I access it directly after I mounted it, the update is much faster.

Here are some error messages from when this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/bin/whisper", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 413, in cli
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
  File "<frozen os>", line 225, in makedirs
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.'
```

or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/bin/whisper", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 437, in cli
    result = transcribe(model, audio_path, temperature=temperature, **args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 339, in transcribe
    print(make_safe(line))
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/bin/whisper", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/transcribe.py", line 438, in cli
    writer(result, audio_path)
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/utils.py", line 201, in write_all
    writer(result, file)
  File "/Users/db/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages/whisper/utils.py", line 83, in __call__
    with open(output_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'my.txt'
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

What do you think is the problem? How to fix?

Comment: things you could try:  1) see smb parameters to do some keepalive.  2) create & delete a "dummy" file on the remote smb server every N minutes (from the same script, ie from the client). 3) maybe the opposite: maybe the remote smb is very rarely unavailable for a few seconds, and your writes happen to "see" that unavailability: try to increase the duration between writes?

Comment: @OlivierDulac Can you multithread a shell script? The whisper step can take several hours and it would be good to "ping" the SMB volume regularly during that step but that would require multithreading (or something that mimics that at least), wouldn't it?

Comment: multithreading depends on your OS. if you have any decent/recent OS you should be able to start a "pinging" subroutine (in a subshell) running in the background of your bash script. something like: `keepalive() { while [ ! -f /some/path/file_appearing_when_script_finished_working ]; do touch /path/to/smb/keepalive; rm -f  /path/to/smb/keepalive; sleep 300 ; } ; keepalive & ` . Near the beginning of your bash script (and add a `touch /some/path/file_appearing_when_script_finished_working` when the script finishes working). Of course this is a bad exemple, but just to get you started